# Error Code: 80070008 during Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview installation!

Tags: update, 8.1

Today Windows 8.1 Developer preview for Windows Phone 8 devices are available.
I tried to update with my developer account, But after completion of the all steps, i am getting an error!
Look the image below.
It indicates an Error Code: 80070008

[image: Windows Phone 8.1 Error Code 80070008]

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also received that on one of my devices during the upgrade. I was able to try again a few minutes later. My wifi had cut out and the download process didn't continue.

You should have no problem attempting the upgrade again.

Comment: I tried many times! almost 7 times! But all time i failed with that error codes!
PS: My memory is 2 GB Free! My charged was plugged in too.

Comment: Upon doing some additional research, it looks like this error can also be that the update server is too busy. It may take some patience.http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/windows-update-error-800705b4-80070008-or-8007000e

Answer (score 1):

i received that error too, and i don't know what reason behind this error
but i try this method and the update go smooth..

first Flash your Windows Phone to factory setting (setting-about-reset)
or hard reset it (when wp turn off hold down power button + volume down)
and then if the flash success you can update your phone to 8.1.

ps: your phone will update several time before getting the 8.1 update

psss: if you brick your phone when flash it, you should download stock firmware and install the stock tou your phone with NSU for Retail (you can search that on XDA)